# Property 'entityManagerFactory' is required

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I just started to develop an application that's meant to support an already existing web project, therefore the business and persistence layers already exist and are working very well within that web application. Now as I use the libs for both layers in my console application I get an error that the JpaTransactionManager requires the entityManagerFactory, which is weird, because it doesn't throw an exception in my web app. All I do in my console application is creating the application context

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("engine-context.xml");

}
```

the engine-context.xml:

```
<import resource="business-context.xml" />
<import resource="persistence-context.xml" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spielerService' defined in class path resource [business-context.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myTxManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myTxManager' defined in class path resource [persistence-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'entityManagerFactory' is required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.boogerrangers.engine.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.java:14) 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myTxManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myTxManager' defined in class path resource [persistence-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'entityManagerFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:820)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:446)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myTxManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myTxManager' defined in class path resource [persistence-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'entityManagerFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myTxManager' defined in class path resource [persistence-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'entityManagerFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'entityManagerFactory' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JpaTransactionManager.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 39 more
```

All I do in my web application is to define the context XML files in the web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        classpath:persistence-context.xml   
        classpath:business-context.xml          
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

there's no more magic in the applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- SESSION: -->
    <bean name="spielerSession" class="org.boogerrangers.persistence.dom.SpielerLogin" scope="session"  >
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>

<!-- FILTER: -->
    <bean name="authFilter" class="org.boogerrangers.game.filter.AuthFilter" >
    </bean>
```

--

persistence-context

```
<context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="xxx" />
        <property name="username" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
    </bean>


    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="myTxManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="servicePointcut" expression="execution(* *..*Service*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="servicePointcut" />
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="xxx"></property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

... DAOs ...
```

more information needed?

as a dirty workaround I created a new persistence-context and use this instead but that's confusing and I don't wanna have redundant configurations. I also created a second webapp doing the same thing as in the standalone app with no thrown exceptions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you import the xml file as resources (in which txManager is defined) into the file which contains reference of this bean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JpaTransactionManager` should be supplied with `EntityManagerFactory`:

```
<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Its `dataSource` property is optional, it's only needed if you are going to mix JPA with plain JDBC access.

Comment: but why does it work in my web application? without the emf and just the datasource. but thanks, i'm gonna change it this way

Comment: @tagtraeumer: You don't include `engine-context.xml` in application context of your webapp, therefore it doesn't use transaction management at all.

Comment: of course not, because the webapp includes all contexts in the web.xml. the engine-context.xml doesn't contain anything the webapp needs. this error happens btw even if i don't use the engine context and directly call the context files like following: `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("engine-context.xml");`

Comment: `engine-context.xml` context contains `<tx:annotation-driven>`, how else would you enable transactions in webapp?

Comment: using aop `<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="myTxManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="servicePointcut" expression="execution(* *..*Service*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="servicePointcut" />
    </aop:config>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems the data source is injected in the transaction manager

```
<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

But in our case, you need to use the entity manager instead of the data source, as you use **JPA transaction manager**:

```
<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: hmm but why does it work in my web application? i only use the datasource and no emf. i guess, i'm going to provide the JpaTM with both so i can get rid of my additional context xml. thanks